# Populate multidimensional array's rank column with dense rank number

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, ranking, dense-rank

My array structure is as follows -

```
[
    [
        "points" => 10,
        "details" => ["name" => "Team A", "rank" => ""]
    ],
    [
        "points" => 10,
        "details" => ["name" => "Team B", "rank" => ""]
    ],
    [
        "points" => 8,
        "details" => ["name" => "Team C", "rank" => ""]
    ],
    [
        "points" => 6,
        "details" => ["name" => "Team D", "rank" => ""]
    ],
]
```

Now I want populate the array's "rank" value with the appropriate dense rank.  Expected result:

```
[
    [
        "points" => 10,
        "details" => ["name" => "Team A", "rank" => 1]
    ],
    [
        "points" => 10,
        "details" => ["name" => "Team B", "rank" => 1]
    ],
    [
        "points" => 8,
        "details" => ["name" => "Team C", "rank" => 2]
    ],
    [
        "points" => 6,
        "details" => ["name" => "Team D", "rank" => 3]
    ],
]
```

How can I achieve this output? I tried looping through each element in the array and comparing points, but I didn't find that to be really efficient.

Answer (score 1):

How about to create another array and store desired result there

```
$array = array(
    array(
        "points" => 10,
        "details" => array(
            "name" => "Team A",
            "rank" => ""
        )
    ),
    array(
        "points" => 11,
        "details" => array(
            "name" => "Team B",
            "rank" => ""
        )
    )
);

$c = 0; // count identifier
$n = array(); // create new array

for ($i=0;$i<count($array);$i++){ // loop through each array
    foreach ($array[$i] as $value){ // loop through into sub arrays
        if (is_array($value)){
            $n[$i]['details'] = array(
                "name" => $value['name'],
                "rank" => $c
            );
            $c++;
        } else {
            $n[$i]['points'] = $value;
        }
    }
}

print_r($n);
```

Output will be:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [points] => 10 [details] => Array ( [name] => Team A [rank] => 0 ) ) [1] => Array ( [points] => 11 [details] => Array ( [name] => Team B [rank] => 1 ) ) )
```

Answer (score 1):

A bit bruteforce but it should work.

```
$array = array(
    array(
    "points" => 10,
    "details" => array(
        "name" => "Team A",
        "rank" => ""
    )
    ),
    array(
    "points" => 11,
    "details" => array(
        "name" => "Team B",
        "rank" => ""
    )
    ),
    array(
    "points" => 10,
    "details" => array(
        "name" => "Team A",
        "rank" => ""
    )
    ),
    array(
    "points" => 11,
    "details" => array(
        "name" => "Team B",
        "rank" => ""
    )
    )
);
$points = array();
foreach($array as $key => $arr){
    $points[] = $arr['points'];
}
asort($points);

foreach($points as $pkey => $point){
    foreach($array as $akey => $arr){
        if($point == $arr['points']){
            $array[$akey]['details']['rank'] = $pkey+1;
        }
    }
}


var_dump($array);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your multidimensional input array is already sorted descending by the `points` column, you can loop through the array and modify its `rank` data by reference while conditionally incrementing the rank variable.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/2AuBR))

```
$denseRank = 0;
foreach ($array as ['points'=> $points, 'details' => ['rank' => &$rank]]) {
    $denseRanks[$points] ??= ++$denseRank;
    $rank = $denseRanks[$points];
}
var_export($array);
```

The above snippet uses "array destructuring" in the `foreach()` to declare only used variables; it is just as viable to declare `&$row` and then access its elements in the loop's body.