# How to select duplication rank with php from multiple array

Tags: php

I am working on a Database that manipulates college students exam results. Basically, I am pulling the records from a MySql Database, puling one class at any given time. I want to rank the students, with the highest performer at number 1.

I have try to read this article but it show me only single array :

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6163225/how-do-i-rank-array-values-with-duplicate-values-and-skipping-some-positions-if
```

Here is an illustration;

get result and make and array

```
$grades = array();
    foreach($results->result() as $row){

        $grades[] = array('rank'=>$row->total,'name'=>$student_name);

    }
```

array result :

```
$grades[] = array(
array('rank'=>"123","name"=>"samphors"),
array('rank'=>"123","name"=>"sovann"),
array('rank'=>"102","name"=>"dy vann"),
array('rank'=>"113","name"=>"koro vann")
);
```

So I want to capture Mysql data as a multiple array. Once I have the data in an array, I should then assign each student a position in the class such as 1/10 (number 1, the 123 score), 4/10 etc. Now the problem is that if there is a tie, then the next score skips a position and if there are 3 scores at one position then the next score skips 2 positions. So the scores above would be ranked as follows;

```
----------------------------------
| no | name       | score | rank |
| 1  |samphors    | 123   | 1    |
| 2  |sovann      | 123   | 1    |
| 3  |koro vann   | 113   | 2    |
| 4  |dy vann     | 102   | 3    |
----------------------------------
```

Is it possible (humanly possible /php possible) to use PHP to rank the scores and name of student above in such a way that it can handle possible ties such as 4 scores at one position? SADLY, I could not come up with a function to do this. I need a PHP function (or something ... PHP) that will take an array and produce a ranking as above.

Any help will be deeply appreciated, though I think I may be asking for too much. If it's possible to do this with MySQL query data without having it in an array, then that will also be helpful!

Comment: have you tried adding "order by rank asc" to the end of your sql query?

Comment: I don't understand the formula, how the rank should be calculated. Please, provide and example of such calculation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution with PHP.
This requires that your results are ordered by `score ASC`.

```
<?php

// Start array
$grades = array(
  array('score' => "123", "name" => "samphors"),
  array('score' => "123", "name" => "sovann"),
  array('score' => "113", "name" => "koro vann"),
  array('score' => "102", "name" => "dy vann")
);

$i         = 0;
$prevScore = 0;

foreach ( $grades as &$grade ) {
  // Increment rank only if scores different
  if( $grade[ 'score' ] != $prevScore ){
    $i++;
  }

  $prevScore = $grade[ 'score' ];
  $grade[ 'rank' ] = $i;
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($grades);
echo '</pre>';

?>
```

Output:

```
Array
(
  [0] => Array
      (
          [score] => 123
          [name] => samphors
          [rank] => 1
      )

  [1] => Array
      (
          [score] => 123
          [name] => sovann
          [rank] => 1
      )

  [2] => Array
      (
          [score] => 113
          [name] => koro vann
          [rank] => 2
      )

  [3] => Array
      (
          [score] => 102
          [name] => dy vann
          [rank] => 3
      )

)
```

Comment: Even if you dont use ASC in your MySQL, you can do a usort in PHP to the Array to sort it.

Answer (score 0):

You should alter your mysql query as

```
SELECT * FROM `your table name` ORDER BY `rank` ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

This will handle ranks with the same score. basically you will have to do it in your query.

```
SELECT  d.*, c.ranks
FROM
    (
      SELECT    Score, @rank:=@rank+1 Ranks
      FROM
              (
                  SELECT  DISTINCT Score 
                  FROM    tableName a
                  ORDER   BY score DESC
              ) t, (SELECT @rank:= 0) r
    ) c 
    INNER JOIN tableName d
        ON c.score = d.score
```