# Add order column to array to indicate rank from oldest to youngest

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, increment, dense-rank

In PHP7, If I have this array:

```
$array = [
    ["name" => "Jon", "age" => 44],
    ["name" => "Bob", "age" => 32],
    ["name" => "Jim", "age" => 103],
    ["name" => "Ted", "age" => 19]
];
```

What is the most elegant way to process this array to add an extra column indicating who is the oldest to who is the youngest like so...

```
[
    ["name" => "Jon", "age" => 44, "order" => 2],
    ["name" => "Bob", "age" => 32, "order" => 3],
    ["name" => "Jim", "age" => 103, "order" => 1],
    ["name" => "Ted", "age" => 19, "order" => 4]
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without a point of reference to determine which is the oldest user you're stuck either doing a multi loop comparison or a sort then insert.

A Multi loop comparasin would look something like

```
<?php
$array = [
  ["name" => "Jon", "age" => 44],
  ["name" => "Bob", "age" => 32],
  ["name" => "Jim", "age" => 103],
  ["name" => "Ted", "age" => 19]
];

$count = count($array);

for($index = 0; $index < $count; ++$index) {
  $order = 1;
  $age = $array[$index]["age"];
  for($index2 = 0; $index2 < $count; ++$index2) {
    if($array[$index2]["age"] > $age) {
      ++$order;
    }
  }

  $array[$index]["order"] = $order;
}

echo "<pre>";
var_dump($array);
echo "</pre>";
```

Sort then insert would involve `array_walk` and `uasort`

From the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php)

```
<?php
$fruits = array("d" => "lemon", "a" => "orange", "b" => "banana", "c" => "apple");

function test_alter(&$item1, $key, $prefix)
{
  $item1 = "$prefix: $item1";
}

function test_print($item2, $key)
{
  echo "$key. $item2<br />\n";
}

echo "Before ...:\n";
array_walk($fruits, 'test_print');

array_walk($fruits, 'test_alter', 'fruit');
echo "... and after:\n";

array_walk($fruits, 'test_print');
```

and [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uasort.php)

```
<?php
// Comparison function
function cmp($a, $b) {
  if ($a == $b) {
    return 0;
  }
  return ($a < $b) ? -1 : 1;
}

// Array to be sorted
$array = array('a' => 4, 'b' => 8, 'c' => -1, 'd' => -9, 'e' => 2, 'f' => 5, 'g' => 3, 'h' => -4);
print_r($array);

// Sort and print the resulting array
uasort($array, 'cmp');
print_r($array);
```

so for your example it would be something like this:

```
<?php
function walkFunc(&$item, $key) {
  $item["order"] = $key + 1;
}

// as @waterloomatt mentioned the Spaceship operator is meant for this
function sortComp($a, $b) {
  return ($a["age"] <=> $b["age"]) * -1;
}

$array = [
  ["name" => "Jon", "age" => 44],
  ["name" => "Bob", "age" => 32],
  ["name" => "Jim", "age" => 103],
  ["name" => "Ted", "age" => 19]
];

uasort($array, 'sortComp');
array_walk($array, 'walkFunc');

echo "<pre>";
var_dump($array);
echo "</pre>";
```

Answer (score 1):

Here we are using multiple function to obtain desired output. `array_column` for extracting column `age`, the we are reverse sorting the column using `arsort($columns);` then `getting` `array_values`, then we are flipping array to get its order for age  using `array_flip`, at last we are using `array_map` and `array_merge` to iterate and add a column in the array.

[**Try this code snippet here**](https://eval.in/798542)

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
$array = [
    ["name" => "Jon", "age" => 44],
    ["name" => "Bob", "age" => 32],
    ["name" => "Jim", "age" => 103],
    ["name" => "Ted", "age" => 19]
];
$columns=  array_column($array, "age");//obtaining column age
arsort($columns);//sorting column in reverse

$column=array_flip(array_values($columns));//getting order for age
$result=array_map(function($value) use(&$column){
    $value=  array_merge($value,array("order"=>$column[$value["age"]]+1));//adding age column to array by adding index with 1
    return $value;

}, $array);
print_r($result);
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => Jon
            [age] => 44
            [order] => 2
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => Bob
            [age] => 32
            [order] => 3
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [name] => Jim
            [age] => 103
            [order] => 1
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [name] => Ted
            [age] => 19
            [order] => 4
        )

)
```

Comment: This gapped ranking snippet acts awkwardly when there are ties.  See how there is no 3rd rank with this sample set: https://3v4l.org/9r7db

Answer (score 0):

Not going to lie, I just wanted to use the new spaceship operator. This does not add a new column but will instead sort the array descending by age.

```
<?php

$array = [
    ["name" => "Jon", "age" => 44],
    ["name" => "Bob", "age" => 32],
    ["name" => "Jim", "age" => 103],
    ["name" => "Ted", "age" => 19]
];

usort($array, function ($a, $b) { 
    return ($a["age"] <=> $b["age"]) * -1; 
});

print_r($array);
```

Comment: This answer does not attempt to answer the question.  `($a["age"] <=> $b["age"]) * -1;` is more simply written as `$b["age"] <=> $a["age"];`

Answer (score 0):

To assign dense ranks to each row based on the `age` values, avoid using nested loops and convoluted piles of array functions.  These techniques will have poor time complexity (efficiency) and/or will be very hard to maintain.

Instead, enjoy the sweet convenience of reference variables.  Loop the input array just once and assign references to the new, desired `order` element in each row.  To see what this does, view [this](https://3v4l.org/DDsuL) -- these `null` values will be replaced by the calculated order.

Next, sort the keys of the ref array in a descending order.

Finally, iterate the sorted array and assign incremented values by reference.  Because the ref array elements are "linked" to the `$array` rows, the placeholder elements instantly receive the new values.

The first loop is "linear" -- meaning that that it doesn't need to iterate the array more than once.  The second loop may do fewer iterations than the first if duplicate ages are encountered.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/ZRqfT))

```
foreach ($array as &$row) {
    $row['order'] = &$ref[$row['age']];
}
krsort($ref);
$order = 0;
foreach ($ref as &$v) {
    $v = ++$order;
}
var_export($array);
```